# Composer Autoload is not loading the Class

Tags: php, composer-php

I am new to using composer and psr-0. I have tried a small app using composer and psr-0. I have used namespace to load a particular class. When i call a class using composer vendor/autoload I am getting class not found error.

My composer.json file:/var/www/html/silexapp/composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "symfony/console": "~2.6"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "/silexapp/app"
    }
}
}
```

My composer vendor autoload file: /var/www/html/silexapp/vendor/autoload.php

```
     <?php

      // autoload.php @generated by Composer

     require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

    return ComposerAutoloaderInitf7241d907c173a8d77da0791cc918856::getLoader();
```

My class file name Underline.php: /var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Command/Underline.php

```
      <?php 
      namespace MyApp\Tnq\Todo\Command;
     class Underline{

        public function add($a,$b){

        return $result = $a+$b;

     }

   }

  ?>
```

My another class file name Bold.php: /var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Command/Bold.php

```
    <?php
    require_once "../../../../vendor/autoload.php";
    //require_once "Underline.php";

   use MyApp\Tnq\Todo\Command as tool;

   echo "this is the index file to check namespace.";
   $c = new tool\Underline();
   echo "=============================";
   echo "Addition : ".$c->add(2,2);
   ?>
```

I am getting "class not found error" in my bold.php class file, when I use autoload file. But when I directly included the underline class file, I am getting the output. Why it is not working when I use autoload?

Can anyone help me to find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "key" should be a directory under the path you put as "value", that should be **relative** to your working directory. To look at it in a simple way, the `namespace` should map the directory structure; you are missing a `MyApp` directory.

If in your `composer.json` have:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

Then you need a `MyApp` directory under `app/`. Try this:

composer.json:

```
// /var/www/html/silexapp/composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
        "symfony/console": "~2.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Tnq\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Underline.php:

```
<?php
// /var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Command/Underline.php 
namespace Tnq\Todo\Command;

class Underline
{
    public function add($a,$b)
    {
        return $result = $a+$b;
    }
}
```

Bold.php:

```
<?php
// /var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Command/Bold.php
require_once "../../../../vendor/autoload.php";

use Tnq\Todo\Command as tool;

echo 'this is the index file to check namespace.' . PHP_EOL;
$c = new tool\Underline();
echo "=============================";
echo "Addition : ".$c->add(2,2);
```

In theory, that should works (not tested :) )

---

sources:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/